# How can I enable High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) for my Bluetooth Headset?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

When I open Sound Settings and change the Profile from "Headset" to "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)".

When I change it, PulseAudio reports the following error:

```
W: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-device.c: Refused to switch profile to a2dp_sink: Not connected
```

How can I change profiles?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure PulseAudio believes your device is connected - even if you think it is.

Run the command `bluetoothctl` and look at the devices connected. I have 2:

```
[NEW] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:11 Hairy16 [default]
[NEW] Device E8:07:BF:12:FA:4A AUSDOM AH861
[NEW] Device 90:B9:31:77:B7:78 Tim's iPhone
```

type the command `connect <ADDR>`, where `<ADDR>` is the 12 letter address of your device - e.g. `E8:07:BF:12:FA:4A`. You should see the following:

```
[bluetooth]# connect E8:07:BF:12:FA:4A 
Attempting to connect to E8:07:BF:12:FA:4A
Connection successful
[DEVICE NAME]#
```

Then you can change the profile successfully.

Comment: Still a bug in Ubuntu 19 and that fixed it.

Comment: to display connected devices you may want to issue `bluetoothsctl devices`

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in current 8.0 in 16.04. See more here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1574324

I'm currently helping the devs figure out what patch is broken. In the meantime, write an email to me from launchpad, and I will help you with a version without those patches.