# Change Bluetooth Headphones default audio mode (A2DP Sink vs HSP/HFP)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 18.10, headphones

I have Sony [WH-1000XM2](https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/wh-1000xm2/specifications) Bluetooth 4.1 headphones (with [profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles) [A2DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_(A2DP)), [AVRCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Audio/Video_Remote_Control_Profile_(AVRCP)), [HFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Hands-Free_Profile_(HFP)), and [HSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Headset_Profile_(HSP))) which work with Ubuntu [18.10](/questions/tagged/18.10).

However, they constantly connect to the PC in the headset mode with subpar mono audio. For proper high def stereo, I must:

1. Turn on headphones, wait for them to pair (auto connects to headset mode)
2. Disconnect the headphones using [Blueman-manager](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman)
3. Reconnect to the headphones specifying the High Fidelity Playback Audio Profile.

When I try to change profiles while connected I get the `Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink`. Funnily enough it can change from `a2dp` to `hsp/hsf` just fine...

Is there a way to configure this Bluetooth device to auto connect to high fidelity playback?

Multiple searches for a solution on the web have found nothing useful.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002081/367990) helped me to have the headset be recognized and detected automatically as new default sound device once it connected via bluetooth. Maybe it might improve your situation too, even if it doesn't look too related on first sight?

Comment: You may find https://askubuntu.com/questions/806215/how-can-i-enable-high-fidelity-playback-a2dp-sink-for-my-bluetooth-headset helpful.

Comment: I switched my 22.04 installation from pulseaudio to pipewire with [this installation instruction](https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e) and me headset now correctly switched between HFP and A2DP depending on if an application uses the microphone.

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same problem. My Sony **WH-1000XM2** used to work only when initially paired with **Ubuntu 18.04**. After a reboot or headphones off/on they used to connect automatically but the sound was awful. I had to remove the Bluetooth device and pair it again. I tried all of the solutions on the Internet which claim that configurations in:

```
/etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

or

```
/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
```

should do the trick. Well, they don't. The headphones keep working with the **'HSP/HFP'** profile and the **'A2DP Sink'** can not be set until the phones are repaired.

The more convenient way is to use the command line instead of physically pressing buttons and reconnecting through the UI. So [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/773391/283436) helped me achieve this.
However, this looks like a lot of commands to me, so I scripted them in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/egelev/2e6b57d5a8ba62cf6df6fff2878c3fd4). It should work out of the box.

Whenever the phones get automatically reconnected (after the initial pairing) and they start using **'HSP/HFP'** just execute this script and the profile will be set to **'A2DP Sink'**. You may have to tweak the sleep intervals according to your headphones.

I hope this is getting fixed in upcoming releases of PulseAudio and Ubuntu.

Comment: This is spot on, thanks for your gist! It worked for my Sony WH-CH700N headphones first time.

Comment: I confirm gist works with JBL.

Comment: This is not working with Sony WH1000XM4. They are still going to HSP after running the gist.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 20.04

I was able to select the `A2DP` profile for my headphones (Bose QC 700). I was **able to select A2DP**, but every time the headphones disconnected, it would **default** to the `HSP/HFP` profile.

Following the solution mentioned [here](https://sandalov.org/blog/2146/) and [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-automatically-switch-sound-output-device-to-bluetooth-headset-force-to-a2dp-profile-on-connection/), `A2DP` is now selected automatically at every connection:

- Add to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to automatically switch pulseaudio sink to Bluez:

```
.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-switch-on-connect  # Add this
.endif
```

- Edit `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` to auto select A2DP profile (instead of HSP/HFP):

```
[General]
Disable=Headset # Add this
```

- Apply changes (you may as well need to turn your bluetooth headphones off, then back on):

```
pulseaudio -k                       # Kills pulseaudio
pulseaudio --start                  # Starts pulseaudio
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Comment: This works! - Excellent answer! Linking to solutions AND adding the solution to the answer... :)

Comment: That works like a charm.

Comment: This works for me only until I restart the OS, afterwards the head-phone profile is default again. If I manually restart pulseaudio and bluetooth then the bug goes away. Would be nice to not have to do this manual step

Answer (score 1):

I wound up writing a custom script to do this. You're going to have to adjust the Bluetooth address in order to make it work correctly for your own headset:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEV_ID="6C_5A_B5_4A_4C_37"

LOCKFILE=/tmp/setup-bt_ad2p.pid
if [ -e ${LOCKFILE} ] && kill -0 `cat ${LOCKFILE}`; then
    echo "already running"
    exit
fi

# make sure the lockfile is removed when we exit and then claim it
trap "rm -f ${LOCKFILE}; exit" INT TERM EXIT
echo $$ > ${LOCKFILE}

/usr/bin/gdbus monitor --system --dest org.bluez |
    while read -r X; 
    do
        if echo $X | grep  "${DEV_ID}.*'Connected': <true>"
        then
            echo -n "BT headset detected, configuring "
            date
            pacmd  set-card-profile bluez_card.${DEV_ID} a2dp_sink
        fi
    done
```

I run this script from autostart, and it's been working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. As egelev states, many of the solutions do not really solve anything...

However, for future reference, I found a solution involving changing /etc/pulse/default.pa which worked perfectly for me, the full solution can be found [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-automatically-switch-sound-output-device-to-bluetooth-headset-force-to-a2dp-profile-on-connection/). In short, doing the following automatically changes the profile to A2DP and disables the headphone function upon connecting to bluetooth headphones with mics:

```
# In /etc/pulse/default.pa do the following:
.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-switch-on-connect # Add this line
.endif


# Create or change /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf with the following lines:
[General]
Disable=Headset

# Restart pulseaudio
pulseaudio -k
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I forgot that I installed `pipewire` which in combination with the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` package conflicts with the **a2dp** (advanced audio distribution profile). Hence, check if `pipewire` is running

```
ps -e | grep pipewire
```

If it is running either uninstall pipewire and keep the pulseaudio-module-bluetooth module or you can give pipewire a chance, since it has advanced options and performance.

- **Keeping pipewire**

  First uninstall the following module at the command line with

  ```
  sudo apt remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  ```

  and install all pipewire packages with

  ```
   sudo apt-get install pipewire-*
  ```

  additional add the following code at the end of your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` configuration file:

  ```
  ### Added to make headset work for pipewire
  ### https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp
  load-module module-bluez5-device 
  load-module module-bluez5-discover
  ```

  On my plasma desktop all codecs are now available:

  [image]
- **Keeping default pulseaudio-module**

  In case you use the default pulseaudio setup from ubuntu simple uninstall or disable `pipwire` e.g.:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove pipewire*
  ```

More information about the a2dp problem can be found on [BluetoothUser/a2dp - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp).

**BTW:** My bluetooth hardware is implemented in the `Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201` chip which made it necessary to download (as on March 2022) the latest firmware driver from the linux kernel homepage. The firmware I am using is:

```
> ls  -1 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-*

/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-65.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode
```

Comment: +1 Omg, I can switch right in the audio applet instead of opening the settings all the time (picture says a thousand words). That's going to lower my response time by half a minute when people try to call me on Teams. I haven't tried pipewire, but pulseaudio works fine.

Comment: Pipewire is the default audio set on Fedora and many other distributions. Maybe ubuntu will also switch as others have done.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like that to /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
load-module module-switch-on-connect
.endif

.ifexists module-bluez5-device.so
load-module module-bluez5-device
.endif

.ifexists module-bluez5-discover.so
load-module module-bluez5-discover
.endif
```

Restart bluetooth and pulseaudio services.