# Ubuntu 22.04 does not recognize my microphone's headset when plugging in, just audio

Tags: microphone, 22.04, headset

On another laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS every time I plugged in my (current) headset (Sony in-ear extrabass) a window popped up to choose between headphones or headset, although this popup was annoying it was the way to use my microphone's headset.
I sold the previous laptop and now that I am using another one (Asus rog strix G513QM), I installed Ubuntu 22.04 from 0. Firstly, no such window pops up when I plug in my headset. Secondly, even searching in the system does not show the microphone of my headsets to choose them manually.
Please, maybe someone knows how to do so that (1) the selection window pops up again and/or (2) my system can recognize the microphone of my headsets automatically or even do it manually.
PS. Both the microphone and audio on my headset work perfectly, as I use them on my cellphone and tablet, with no issues.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what headset? what laptop? need more details.

Comment: Headsets often have 2 "modes": one with high-quality audio *only*, and one with lower-quality audio *and* mic input. Can you switch between the two in Settings?

Comment: @Esther Thank you for replying. Already edited the details of my headset and laptop. And I can't switch between those two options.

Comment: Ironically, I just found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141226/change-bluetooth-headphones-default-audio-mode-a2dp-sink-vs-hsp-hfp/1413729) asking to do the exact opposite (default to audio mode, not headset mode). maybe it will be helpful

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it didn't help 'cause my headset is wired (not Bluetooth). Thanks anyway @Esther.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title in this site. The green check mark ✅ next to the correct answer is sufficient. See [this question and answer in Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7413/attaching-solved-to-title-of-questions-with-accepted-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem.
I thought I had tried everything until I found this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163677/980324).

I did everything exactly, step by step, at the end I rebooted and it did recognize the microphone of my headset.

Now, although every time I plug in my headset I don't get the option to choose between headphones or headset (as Ubuntu 20.04 did before), when I plug it in it does make the difference between 'Internal microphone' and only 'Microphone' in the 'Input' Sound Settings.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 22.04, and I followed this link. I got the headset mic to work. However, in the system settings there still only one item (built-in).

Comment: used for Asus Vivobook and Ubuntu 22.04 and it worked