# How can I fix the problem of the external earphone mic or external mic not working in Ubuntu 22.10 while the external earphone speakers are working?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, 22.10

"I have tried several solutions, including:

1. [Ubuntu 22.04 does not recognize my microphone's headset when plugging in, just audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413842/ubuntu-22-04-does-not-recognize-my-microphones-headset-when-plugging-in-just-a)
2. https://candid.technology/ubuntu-microphone-not-working/
3. https://www.onlinemictest.com/microphone-settings/ubuntu/
4. https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

None of them has worked on my laptop, which is a Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC. Although my earphone speakers are working properly and the hardware is being detected, my external mic is not working. Can you please provide a detailed solution to this issue? If I am unable to resolve this issue, I will have no option but to switch back to Windows. I would greatly appreciate your help with this problem."

Comment: You forgot to mention brand of the earphones/headset and what the connection is that you use. Please edit the question so the comment can be removed ;-) There are two main modes: music mode and phone mode. Music mode will disable the mic as it would distort audio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem recently with my Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH, even though in my case I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I tried several suggestions from the first link you provided but nothing worked.

However following the advice given in this [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1287900/1687106) I managed to get the microphone to be detected:

1. Run `hdajackretask`
2. Switch the tab on top to the appropriate sound codec, in my case it was `Realtek ALC257`
3. Tick override in the "Black Mic, right side" section and chose "Microphone" in the dropdown selection
4. "Install boot override" and reboot

At this point, the microphone could be detected in Ubuntu, but I had no sound in the headset so then I did the following steps:

1. Go back to `hdajackretask` on the same codec as before.
2. Tick override in the "Black Headphone, right side" section and chose "Microphone" in the dropdown selection
3. "Install boot override" and reboot
4. Using `alsamixer` make sure all the "headphone" device is at least above zero. If not increase its volume with the arrow keys.

If this doesn't work I suggest trying other options in the dropdown selector in the "Black Mic, Right side" section in `hdajackretask` and then "Install boot override" and reboot at every attempt.