# Can I make bluetooth speaker connect in A2DP by default?

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I have a blue tooth speaker that connects by default as Headset Unit (HSP/HFP). How can I make it connect by default High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)?

I have two users defined on my machine and somehow for one of the users it remembers the connection setting A2DP. But for the other user it doesn't. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Edit: The answer suggested in the comment, http://askubuntu.com/a/1388140/32664, works but only until restart. Afterwards the problem persists. I noticed that if I am doing a manual `pulseaudio -k && sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` then the problem goes away...

Comment: You may want to see if the following solution has any effect on your configuration: https://askubuntu.com/a/1388140/32664.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Bluetooth Headphones default audio mode (A2DP Sink vs HSP/HFP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141226/change-bluetooth-headphones-default-audio-mode-a2dp-sink-vs-hsp-hfp)

Answer (score 0):

Open up the audio.conf file (this should be the path: `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`) while signed as the other user (the one which is not remembered) and see if the option `AutoConnect=true` is commented out or not (if it's not there add it). If it is, remove the # in front of it, exit and save the file, restart bluetooth with the following command: `sudo service bluetooth restart` and try again.
Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't work. I couldn't find an audio.conf but from what I read this was replaced by main.conf on the same path so I added there the line you gave me as it was absent altogether. Did the restart of bluetooth but my device reconnected as headphone quality :/

Comment: My bad, I'll edit this in my answer. About the quality; are your drivers up to date?

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work with the answer pointed out by @richbl in the comment. If the drivers get autoupdated then they are up to date

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution [from here](https://sandalov.org/blog/2146/) worked for me:

Add to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to automatically switch pulseaudio sink to Bluez:

```
.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-switch-on-connect # Add this
.endif
```

Modify `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` to auto select A2DP profile (instead of HSP/HFP):

```
[General]
Disable=Headset # Add this
```

Apply changes (did not work for me, I just rebooted):

```
sudo pulseaudio -k # Restarts pulseaudio
sudo restart --system bluetooth # Restarts BT
```