# How to get bluetooth headset to default to HFP Profile and mSBC codec on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, headset

Currently, whenever I reconnect my Bluetooth headset to Ubuntu 22.04, it defaults to the A2DP Sink profile. I then use pavucontrol to manually switch to HFP every time. How do I get this to stick so I don't have to keep changing it?

I've tried the solutions in [Change Bluetooth Headphones default audio mode (A2DP Sink vs HSP/HFP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141226/change-bluetooth-headphones-default-audio-mode-a2dp-sink-vs-hsp-hfp) and none seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. My headset supports only audio with A2DP and needs to switch to HFP in order for my mic to work.

I switched from pulse audio to pipewire. "Pipewire (WirePlumber >= 0.4.8) [...] supports automatic Bluetooth profile switching (e.g. switching from A2DP to HSP/HFP when an application needs microphone access)."

This was a great solution for my use case. My laptop no longer uses the internal mic when joining MS Teams calls but automatically switches to my headset with HFP.

I am also running Ubuntu 22.04 and [installed Pipewire manually](https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e).

> Install
>
> Install codecs for LDAC (SBC is included out of the box):
>
> $ sudo apt install libldacbt-{abr,enc}2
>
> Install remaining PipeWire packages and WirePlumber as the session
> manager:
>
> $ sudo apt install \   libspa-0.2-bluetooth \
> pipewire-audio-client-libraries \   pipewire-media-session- \
> wireplumber
>
> ```
> Notice '-' at the end of 'pipewire-media-session'. This is to remove it in the same command, because 'wireplumber' will be used
> ```
>
> instead.
>
> Start WirePlumber for your user:
>
> $ systemctl --user --now enable wireplumber.service
>
> Configure ALSA
>
> Single step. Copy the config file from the PipeWire examples into your
> ALSA configuration directory:
>
> $ sudo cp
> /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/alsa.conf.d/99-pipewire-default.conf
> /etc/alsa/conf.d/
>
> PulseAudio
>
> Everything was done automatically by pipewire-pulse package, which
> should have been installed by wireplumber package as recommended. If
> not, install it yourself. Bluetooth
>
> Just remove this package and Bluetooth will be handled by PipeWire:
>
> $ sudo apt remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
>
> Done
>
> Reboot and check if it works by running:
>
> $ LANG=C pactl info | grep '^Server Name'

This is only a workaround and doesn't answer your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem.
A simple command-line-workaround is to set the sink manually after the connect:

Set an alias in your ".profile" or ".bashrc" and simply use "hs" on the command-line after bluetooth-connect

```
alias hs='pacmd set-card-profile bluez_card.your_device handsfree_head_unit'
```

You can find your device with:

```
pacmd list
```

And the name will be something like this:

```
name: <bluez_card.AB_CD_EF_12_34_56>
```

After your Bluetooth headset is connected do:

```
hs
```

You can add a headphones setting easily too. For example:

```
    alias hp='pacmd set-card-profile bluez_card.your_device a2dp_sink'
```

I'm still looking for an automatic solution, too.

Comment: Thank you for this - this is a helpful answer so I have upvoted it. It doesn't answer the question so I haven't accepted it yet. Please answer again (i.e. don't edit this) if you come up with an automatic solution. For me, I actually want to be able to easily switch as I also listen to music, so your solution is perfect for that.